# Insert Into SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

я добавляю значение в таблицу с помощью INSERT INTO USERS...
Как я могу проверить имеется ли такие данные?

Comment: Сделать `select * from users` и посмотреть.Но вероятно вы хотите что то автоматизировать. только не говорите, что именно и для чего конкретно вы хотите выполнить проверку

Comment: Я хочу проверить если ли данные с ником, который храниться в строке, в этой таблице. Если нет, добавлять данные.

Comment: Сделайте поле ник уникальным (unique) и вставляйте с помощью `insert or ignore into users ...`. Еще можете посмотреть фразу "on conflict" https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html